# Proving the given inequality. (Complex Analysis).

Tags: complex-analysis

We're given a function $P_n(x)$ for $-1\leq x\leq1$ as follows :

$$P_n(x) = \int \limits_0^\pi \dfrac{1}{\pi}(x+i\sqrt{1-x^2} \cos\theta)^n \, d\theta$$

for $n=(0,1,2,3,\ldots)$, we need to prove that $|P_n(x)| \leq 1$.

I tried the following :

Let $z=x+i\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos\theta$

I somehow want to prove that $|z|=|x+i\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos\theta|\leq1$, as that would imply that $|z^n|\leq1$, as $|z^n|=|z|^n$.

$$|z| = \sqrt{x^2+(1-x^2)\cos^2 \theta} \Longrightarrow \sqrt{x^2 \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta}.$$

Now, $x^2\leq1$ and $\sin^2\theta \leq1 \Longrightarrow x^2\sin^2\theta \leq1$.

Also, $\cos^2\theta \leq1 \Longrightarrow \sqrt{x^2\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta} \leq \sqrt{2}$,

But " $\leq1$" condition is required...

That's the point where I am stuck, could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $(x^2+(1-x^2) \cos^2\theta) \leq (x^2+(1-x^2))=1$, because $\theta$ is real.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x^2\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t
&=x^2(1-\cos^2 t+\cos^2 t\\
&=(1-x^2)\cos^2t+x^2\\
\text{so}\\
|x^2\sin^2t+\cos^2t|
&\le|(1-x^2)\cos^2t+x^2|\\
&\le|(1-x^2)\cos^2t|+|x^2|\\
&\le|1-x^2|+|x^2|\\
&\le(1-x^2)+x^2\\
&=1
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

why not do it like:
for the above to be true we assume the condition to be true and then equating both we will get $x^2\le 1$ which is always true for the given case. Hence, by true logic.